# AS3-Use variable inside the function

Tags: actionscript-3

```
function displayQues():void
{
    //------display question
    for (var i:uint=0; i<numQues; i++)
    {
        q_list.push(i);
    }
    for (var j:uint=0; j<numQues; j++)
    {
        var q:Ans = new Ans();
        q.stop();
        q.x = (j + 1) * 200;// set position
        q.y = 500;

        var r:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * q_list.length);
        q.qface = q_list[r];// assign face to card
        q_list.splice(r,1);
        // remove face from list;
        q.gotoAndStop(q.qface+1);
        addChild(q);
    }
}
```

This is the function i use to display random questions (which are symbol in another movieclip). If i want to reset the positions of the questions after dragging, by click on the reset button, what should i do? I need to use 'q' inside the function displayQues? how to solve it? or if i want to make the 'q' invisible or destroy, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Er- your question is quite hard to understand. But I will try to address it.

Because you do not list `private` or `public` in front your function, I will assume that you are doing everything in the actions window without actionscript classes.

You have a variable, `q`, that you need to reference. However, the reference to `q` is lost to other functions and classes, because `q` is only available within the function that created it.

Here's what I would do; outside of your function block, type this.

```
var ansArray:Array = []
```

Let's create this array, `ansArray`, that stores all of your `Ans`'s. Now, whenever you create a new `Ans`, add it to the `ansArray`, and you will have a more permanent reference that any other function can use.

```
function displayQues():void
{
    //all that other crud
    ansArray.push(q)
}
```